# Chrome Extension Browser Action

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I know you can add a little icon in the top right for extensions, it's really neat, it's a popup. My question is how you you edit the right click menu on it, I can't seem to find something that helps for the life of me. When I right click I get a menu with the name of my extension, but when I click on it, it takes me to a random extension page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it using context menu like this:

1) Add `"permissions": ["contextMenus"]`in manifest.json

2) In background.js, add:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
      title: "hello",
      contexts: ["browser_action"],
      onclick: function() {
        alert('Hello, world!');
      }
});
```

3) This adds "hello" into the menu when you right click on your icon:

[image]

4) The action specified by the onclick function:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that helps a ton.